# how to bind image in image control in asp.net

Tags: c#

i want to bind image in image control but according to the value in Eval

if Eval == True 
then 
  imageurl = "image1"
else
  imageurl = "image"

how to write if condition with eval to get above output

Comment: what you want to do?you want to bind the image with control after checking the condition?on which langauge you are working c#.vb etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%#(Eval("Columnname").ToString()=="True")?"Image1.jpg":"Image2.jpg"%>
```